# Symfony2 Doctrine - Flushing in kernel.response listener flushs bad data

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener, flush

In order to do some logging for my Symfony2 app, I created a service that logs any connection, here is the method called on kernel.response :

```
public function log(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $log = new Log();
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    //fill the Log entity with stuff from request & response data

    $manager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $manager->persist($log);
    $manager->flush();
}
```

All of this seems fine, however when I execute a test like this one (patch with empty data to trigger a failure):

```
$this->client->request(
    'PATCH', 
    '/users/testificate', 
    array(
        'firstName' => '',
    )
);
```

Which calls this action :

```
protected function processForm($item, $method = 'PATCH')
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new $this->form(), $item, array('method' => $method));
    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $response = new Response();

        // Set the `Location` header only when creating new resources
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            $response->setStatusCode(201);
            $response->headers->set('Location',
                $this->generateUrl(
                    'get_' . strtolower($class), array('slug' => $item->getId()),
                    true // absolute
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            $response->setStatusCode(204);
        }
        $this->em->flush();

        return $response;
    }
    $this->em->detach($item);
    return RestView::create($form, 400);
}
```

Although the test fails, the entity is patched, and of course it must not.
After some search what I've learnt is:

- The parameters enter the form validator
- The validation fails, thus returning a 400 http code without flushing the entity
- However during the validation process, the entity gets hydrated with the invalid data
- When the service is called on kernel.response, the $manager->flush(); flush all the data... including the bad data provided by the PATCH test.

What I've tried thus far:
1) Do a $manager->clear(); before $manager->persist(); ... doesn't change anything
2) Do a $manager->detach($item); if the form validation failed... doesn't change anything

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently stumbled across problems with flushing in `kernel.response` when upgrading from Doctrine 2.3.4 to the latest 2.4 branch.  Try flusing the log entities from `kernel.terminate`.  Leave any modifications to the Response in `kernel.response`.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked :)
I had a temporary solution : inserting manually the data in the database with
    `$connection = $manager->getConnection();`
But your way is better !